# jQuery's autocomplete : customize behavior of "ESCAPE" key press

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery's autocomplete plugin and want to customize the behavior when user press the "ESCAPE" key as below,

1. when user types text to search, its corresponding results are listed. Without selection any result if "ESCAPE" key is pressed, then the search text entered should be removed. [Default Behavior: the search text is retained]

   1. In http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote, user can search multiple times. Assume, he has entered a text and has selected a row from the drop down. Now, he searches again, but without selecting any result, he presses "ESCAPE" key, then the search string alone should be removed (and not the previously selected one).

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#birds").keypress(function (e) {
          if(e.keyCode == 27) {
            $("#birds").val("");
          }}
        });  
});
```

Comment: no it didn't work. it defaults to the search term. tried setting a static string (ex: "some string") as directed.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function( $ ) {
        $( "#input" ).live('keydown', function(e) {    
                var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;     
                if(keyCode == 27)
        {
            //Processing
        }
    });
 }( jQuery ));
```